# Rolling over values from one column to other based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:
`DF1`

```
ID  DatePaid   Remaining
A1  2018-01-01   8500
A2  2018-02-15   2000
A2  2018-02-28   1900
A3  2018-04-12   3000
A3  2018-05-12   2700
A3  2018-05-17   110
A3  2018-06-17   0
A4  2018-06-18   10
A5  2018-07-13   500
```

Now I have another dataframe `DF2` which only have unique IDs from first dataframe, and dates that represent months:

```
ID 2018-01-31 2018-02-28 2018-03-31 2018-04-30 2018-05-31 2018-06-30 2018-07-31
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
```

So based on first dataframe I need to fill the values based on the `Remaining` value that is in the first dataframe that is within the corresponding month ( so for example I take the last value for the `A3` from `2018-05` and put it in the `2018-05-31` column in `DF2`. IF there are no other values for that ID just fill all the remaining columns in `DF` with the value in the most right filled column(roll over to the right).

So the end result is exactly like this

```
ID  2018-01-31 2018-02-28 2018-03-31 2018-04-30 2018-05-31 2018-06-30 2018-07-31
A1  8500        8500        8500      8500        8500        8500         8500
A2   NA         1900        1900      1900        1900        1900         1900
A3   NA          NA          NA       3000        110           0             0
A4   NA          NA          NA        NA         NA           10            10
A5   NA          NA          NA        NA         NA           NA           500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you the data in `df2` form:

```
month_ends = pd.to_datetime(df1.DatePaid).dt.to_period('M')
# also
# month_ends = pd.to_datetime(df1.DatePaid).add(pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0))

(df1.groupby(['ID', month_ends])
    ['Remaining'].last()
    .unstack(-1)
    .ffill(1)
    .reset_index()
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
   ID  2018-01  2018-02  2018-04  2018-05  2018-06  2018-07
0  A1   8500.0   8500.0   8500.0   8500.0   8500.0   8500.0
1  A2      NaN   1900.0   1900.0   1900.0   1900.0   1900.0
2  A3      NaN      NaN   3000.0    110.0      0.0      0.0
3  A4      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     10.0     10.0
4  A5      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN    500.0
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Just wanted to ask how pandas is grouping by the `month_ends` series? Does it treat as an external series set that somehow correposnds to original `DatePaid` column? Or does it go by the index? I usually would create another column for that modified series so wondering if it is better to this way does not matter at all?

Comment: It’s a good question. Groupby takes either a series with matching index or an array with the same length. I believe(but not entirely sure) that later pandas versions with match and filter the corresponding index if a series is passed to groupby

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach.

```
df_ = df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='DatePaid', values='Remaining').fillna(method='ffill',axis=1)
```